# Android: How to implement "Facebook easy login"?

Tags: android, facebook

It's hard to explain in words what I'm talking about.

When you open an app on your phone, sometimes it requires you to give a username/email and password credentials. Some applications have an option to "Login with Facebook" and quickly allows the user to login to facebook. By doing this, it gives you a new account by using your facebook information (I guess?).

I know you can do this with my websites too.

My question is what is this called? does facebook devs have a specific name for this? If so, how can I implement it through android, and even through web development?

Thanks!!

UPDATE: For example: When you log into this stackoverflow site. You are able to click on the "login with Facebook" and quickly login without have to fill in information. I know it's the same way with the stackoverflow android app.

Comment: StackOverflow uses [OpenID](http://openid.net/) for the login procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook uses [OAuth 2.0](http://oauth.net/2/).

Related: [OAuth Facebook API Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200212/oauth-facebook-api-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the word "OpenID". Facebook logins are OpenIDs. Allowing users to use the same credentials for different webpages

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called Facebook Single Sign-On.  The [facebook developer docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/sso/) should be enough to get you started.